# JQuery Selector triggering unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to learn jQuery to expand my abilities, so I tried emulating the jQuery UI ".draggable()" behavior.
The spinet shows the problem directly, I don't understand why the `.mousedown` event is triggering when I click on `#Box`, how can I get it to only trigger when clicking on `#MyBox`?

P.S. This is purely for the purpose of understanding jQuery, I have no intention to use this code anywhere.

```js
var down, x, y

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Box").draggable()
  $("#MyBox").mousedown(function(event){
    down = true
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    x = event.pageX - pos.left;
    y = event.pageY - pos.top;
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function(event){
    down = false
  })
  $(document).mousemove(function(event){
    $("span").text("X: " + event.pageX + " Y: " + event.pageY);
    if(down) 
    {
      $("#MyBox").offset({left:event.pageX-x, top:event.pageY-y})
    }
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  background-color: white;
}

#MyBox {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#Box {
  left: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  
<div class='test'>
  <span>Drag a box</span>
  <div id='MyBox'/>
  <div id='Box'/>
</div>
```

Comment: If myBox is above and you want to stop bubbling/propagation to the box below, than on `mousedown` event add `event.stopPropagation();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close properly the boxes divs. Your browser is doing the job for you and interpreting your code in the following way:

```html
<div class='test'>
  <span>Drag a box</span>
  <div id='MyBox'>
    <div id='Box'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that `Box` is inside `MyBox`. In a simple way, `Box` is part of `MyBox`: if you click in `Box` you are also clicking in `MyBox`.

The problem however can be easily solved: `div` tags should be closed with `</div>` because [the list of self closing tags is limited](https://www.quora.com/Which-HTML-tags-are-self-closing?share=1):

```html
<div class='test'>
  <span>Drag a box</span>
  <div id='MyBox'></div>
  <div id='Box'></div>
</div>
```

There are ways to prevent the event from propagating to parent elements, but in your case you have the issue presented above in your HTML code.

Comment: Thanks for this. Guess I should have mentioned I'm pretty new to html as well.